# Fractional Brownian motion, selfsimilar

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-calculus

> Let $0<H<1$. A real-valued Gaussian process $\left(B_H(t)\right)_{t\geq 0}$ is called *fractional Brownian motion* (fBm) if  $\ \mathbb{E}[B_H(t)]=0$ and
>   $$\mathbb{E}[B_H(t)B_H(s)]={\mathbb{E}[B_H(1)^2]\over2}\left(t^{2H}+s^{2H}-|t-s|^{2H}\right).$$

I would like to prove that a fBm is selfsimilar with parameter $H$, and I found something in the literature:

> For any $a>0$ we have \begin{eqnarray*} \mathbb{E}[B_H(at)B_H(as)] &=& {\mathbb{E}[B_H(1)^2]\over2}\left((at)^{2H}+(as)^{2H}-(a|t-s|)^{2H}\right)\\ &=& a^{2H}\mathbb{E}[B_H(t)B_H(s)]\\ &=& \mathbb{E}\left[\left(a^HB_H(t)\right)\left(a^HB_H(s)\right)\right]
> \end{eqnarray*}
>   Since all processes here are mean zero Gaussian, this equality in covariance implies that $B_H(at)\overset{d}{=}a^HB_H(t)$.

I cannot really follow the conclusion of the last sentence. Any help please.

Comment: Gaussian processes are "uniquely" determined by their mean functions and covariance functions. The last sentence is saying that both $B_H(a t)$ and $a^H B_H(t)$ have zero mean functions, and equal covariance functions, hence they are equal in distribution.

Comment: @Sasha Thanks for the explanation.